# Copying dropbox files on MacOS (shared folder icons)

Tags: finder, icon, dropbox

I have a DropBox account that has folders in it. Some folders are shared and others are not shared. When accessed directly from Finder I can see the shared folders have an icon with three people on it. I have copied all folders to a local directory on my MacBook. However, the folders that were shared in DropBox are still showing up with the three people icon.

Does this mean they are somehow still shared and/or connected with DropBox? When looking at the "Get Info" window the sharing details do not look any different from a folder without the multi-user icon on it.

Why is this icon still showing and how do I change it to a standard folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the folder has a custom icon.

To remove the custom icon:

1. Open the Get Info window for the folder (⌘-I).
2. Click on the folder icon in the top-left corner.
3. Press the Delete key on your keyboard.